# Is it possible to declare an associated type that will represent a trait?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

Is it possible to declare an associated type that will represent a trait? If not, what can I do instead? Trying to do:

```
trait Foo {
    /// A trait representing all types that can be returned from baz()
    type ReturnType;
    fn baz(&self) -> Self::ReturnType;
}
```

The biggest problem I'm running into is with the `Sized` trait, because I want a function that returns a vector of items of a type that implements `ReturnType`:

```
trait Foo {
    type ReturnType;
    // option 1
    fn bar(&self) -> Vec<Self::ReturnType>;
    // option 2
    fn bar<T: Self::ReturnType>(&self) -> Vec<T>;
}
```

The problem with option 1 is that `ReturnType` won't be sized because it's a trait, and the problem with option 2 is the compiler won't recognize the associated type as a trait: `failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module 'Self'` and `use of undeclared trait name 'Self::ReturnType'` (which leads me to think associated types can't specify traits)

EDIT: An example of what I'm trying to do

```
/// Represents all types that store byte-data instead of the actual
/// element
trait BufferedVec {
    /// the trait representing types that can be converted from the byte-data
    type FromBuffer;
    /// return the data at the given index, converted into a given type
    fn get<T: Self::FromBuffer>(&self, index: usize) -> T;
}
```

A user's implementation might be

```
/// An implementation of a BufferedVec
struct MyBufferedVec<'a> {
    data: &'a [Option<Vec<u8>>]
}
impl<'a> BufferedVec for MyBufferedVec<'a> {
    type FromBuffer = MyFromTrait;
    fn get<T: MyFromTrait>(&self, index: usize) -> T {
        <T as MyFromTrait>::convert(self.data[index].as_ref())
    }
}

trait MyFromTrait {
    fn convert(val: Option<&[u8]>) -> Self;
}
impl MyFromTrait for i32 {
    fn convert(val: Option<&[u8]>) -> i32 {
        match val {
             Some(ref bytes) => bytes[0] as i32,
             None            => 0
        }
    }
}
impl MyFromTrait for String {
    fn convert(val: Option<&[u8]>) -> String {
        match val {
             Some(ref bytes) => String::from_utf8(bytes),
             None            => "".to_string()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Associated types cannot specify traits. You can't specify traits anywhere in Rust. You can require that a generic argument (or an associated type) needs to implement a trait.

```
trait Foo {
    type ReturnType: Clone;
}
```

This way any implementors of `Foo` need to make sure that their choice of `ReturnType` also implements `Clone`.

```
impl Foo for Bar {
    type ReturnType: i32;
}
```

Comment: Right; I figured as much

Comment: what's your use-case? There's a good chance Rust has a solution to your actual problem. an MCVE that shows the code that uses your trait and member functions would help a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to build an API. Basically, I'm making traits that a user should implement in order to comply with my API. The problem is I want one of the functions to return something that implements a trait the user defines

Comment: but since you can't use the trait anyway, since you'd know nothing about it, you could just as well allow the user to pass any type.

Comment: ah... generics instead of associated types. makes sense. thanks!

Comment: however I want a function to return a user defined trait. As in, I want my API to allow the user to do `fn foo<T: MyTrait>() -> T`. Is there a way to write a trait so that I can say "implement this function but the generic implements a trait you provide"?

Comment: I seriously need so see code (that won't compile obviously) that shows what behavior you want (including code that uses your types and traits and implements an example type and trait of your hypothetical user)